# How to look for a target in an array using two string array's

Tags: java, arrays

So in looking around for an answer to my question, i have only been able to find map structures or just comparing the strings and having to code to stop. I need to be able to essentially translate between languages and print out the translation and have the user to able to ask again to translate another word. I have 2 strings of 10 matching words from English to Russian. I need to able to use a target (or key) to find the translation. Also I need to use a sequential search.

```
   import java.util.*;
  public class CISCLabTwo
 {
  public static void main (String [] args)
  {
     Scanner keyBoard = new Scanner (System.in);

     String [] english = {"House", "Fat", "Monkey", "Trip", "Jumbo", "Chicken", "Unicorn", "Radio", "Shack", "Xylophone"};
     String [] russian = {"Dom", "Zhir", "Obeziana", "Poezdka", "Ogromniy", "Kuricha", "Edinorog", "Raadiioo", "Hizhina", "Ksilofon"};
     System.out.println ("House, Fat, Monkey, Trip, Jumbo, Chicken, Unicorn, Radio, Shack, Xylophone");
     System.out.println("Enter a Word From Above to Translate to Russian: ");

     int i = 0;

     for (i = 0; i < english.length; i++)
        if (english[i]=target){
           return i;
        }
        else{
           return - 1;
        }
  }//end class
    public static int translate (String [] english, String target)


        }//end main
```

Comment: `i have only been able to find map structures or just comparing the strings and having to code to stop.`  Is there something wrong with those two solutions?

Comment: a.) `english[i]=target` is an assignment. b) you want to use `.equals()` to check for string equality. `==` on a string or any object checks for reference equality, meaning the two operands point to the same address.

Comment: Sam I am- no there is not, but those are not what I am trying to accomplish in this lab.

Answer (score 2):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_search

Basically you create a for-loop checking for a match in the english array.
When you have a match the function will return the position of the string in the given array. Use this position to get the corresponding Russian translation.

```
public static int translate(String [] english, String target)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < english.length; i++){
        if(english[i].equals(target)){
            // Found on position i
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

You might want to rename the function because it doesn't really translate and only returns an integer and not a string.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense to me, but the only problem I'm having is that im not renaming the function but instead trying to use a key or target (unless I'm not understanding what you mean)

Comment: You don't have to rename the function if you don't want to. Use the return value to check in the russian array for the correspondig translation.

Comment: @user2755775 He was merely stating that a function called `translate` suggests that it would return the translated word, not an index.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it's confusing to individually handle two arrays in this way.  You probably want to create an extra class in the same file:

```
class Word {
    String english;
    String russian;
}
```

Then you can create the following array:

```
Word[] words = new Word[10];
```

That way, you can translate using a separate method, as follows:

```
String translate(String eng) {
    for (Word w : words) if (eng.equals(w.english)) return w.russian;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that answer but I don't believe I am allowed to do that, no have I ever done that before.

Answer (score 0):

As for your code, the proper check is in your for-next loop is

```
  if (english[i].equals(target))
     return i;
```

Also, consider whether the case of the words matters.  In your example, is "House" the same as "house"?  If case doesn't matter, you should use *equalsIgnoreCase()* instead of equals, i.e.

```
  if (english[i].equalsIgnoreCase(target))
     return i;
```

(moved later cause it seems like this was homework)

You could save yourself a little work by using two ArrayList to hold the words, since ArrayList has an indexOf() method to do the linear search.  (I have no idea why the Arrays utility class does not have an indexOf method).

That said, a map based structure seems like a much better fit (and will be more efficient).

Comment: -1 `equalsIgnoreCase()` is bad design, the translation for a string may be different if the case is different

Comment: I did say "probably" - since none of his words have all lowercase versions, I doubt if OP was thinking of this.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is get the index, print the Russian word then `break` the loop.

If just printing within main then you can do this.

```
for (i = 0; i < english.length; i++)
{
    if (english[i].equals(target))
    {
       System.out.println(russian[i]; //Print the russian word
       break;                         //stop looping
    }
}
```

Otherwise if you want to have your translate method that returns the index of the word you could do it like so

```
public static int translate (String [] english, String target)
{
     for (i = 0; i < english.length; i++)
     {
         if (english[i].equals(target))
         return i;                    // No need for the else statement as it would
                                      // fail on first iteration if it wasnt the word     
     }
     return -1;                       // After loop exits return -1 as was not found
}
```

Then in main you would call

```
String russianWord = russian[translate(english, target)];
```

Comment: -1 I could see `return russian[i]` as a valid option, but printing it is poor design and makes this code impossible to use in other situations.

Comment: Well that loop is within `main`. So returning is not a valid option. If he was to put it in a method then yes `return russion[i]` woul dbe the correct way, but thats not how its posted

Comment: @user949300 see edit, and is not really poor design for his example since it is within `main` and clearly wanted the russian word printed for the input word